# can't do git stash apply

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, git, github

I tried doing `git stash apply` and I am getting:

```
warning: Cannot merge binary files: app.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/aditya15417.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate (Updated upstream vs. Stashed changes)

Auto-merging app.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/aditya15417.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/aditya15417.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You have a merge conflict in a file that stores data about your workspace (windows and layouts and such). You really ought to exclude those files from your git repository via http://help.github.com/ignore-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xcworkspace files are usually just applicable for the machine & account you're working on (e.g. user name aditya15417) and shouldn't be checked in or tracked via Git.

The only project files I check in to my own GitHub account is "`project.pbxproj`".

So remove them from git via "`git rm ________`" (insert filename there)

Comment: now I am getting CONFLICT (modify/delete): app.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/aditya15417.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate deleted in Updated upstream and modified in Stashed changes. Version Stashed changes of app.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/aditya15417.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate left in tree.

Comment: If (and only if) you don't have anything worth saving in that stash, you can simply do "`git stash drop`".  Or commit only the changes you want to save and then "`git rm`" the xcuserdata files.

Comment: I want to go back to that state before I stash, so there is something important there... not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: in that case, "`git rm`" the xcuserdata files and then do "`git stash apply`" and see if that works.

Comment: You can resolve that conflict in favour of the stashed version of the file with `git checkout --theirs app.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/aditya15417.xcuserdatad/UserInterfa‌​ceState.xcuserstate`, or the version before you tried to apply the stash by using `--ours` instead.  Then use `git add <that-file-name>` to mark that conflict as resolved.

Comment: (The changes to other files represented by your stash should have been successfully applied.)